# Difference in constructor calling with different way of passing arguments

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I am working on the constructor and I passed through this example

```
public class Time2
{
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int seconds;
    public Time2()
    {
        this(0, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

and the second approach is

```
public class Time2
{
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int seconds;
    public Time2()
    {
    }
}
```

I didn't use `this(0,0,0)` in the second approach. What is the difference between using them in this way?

What if I want to add the argument in it?

```
public Time2(int hour)
{
    this(hour, 0, 0);
}
```

Why do we need to add `null` or `0` instead of not adding of not adding anything at all?

Comment: the code is not compiling for the first case, if you do not have a 3 arguments constructor.
`this` calls another constructor with the given number of matching arguments - so you can specify default values

Comment: so this(0,0,0) in the first code will find a constructor with 3 arguments? and what if won't find any? will it run a default constructor then?

Comment: No, it won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Time2()
{
    this(0,0,0)
}
```

and

```
public Time2()
{
}
```

will have the same behavior if the `Time2(int hour,int minute,int seconds)` constructor only assigns the values passed to it to the 3 instance variables (hour, minutes & seconds), since these instance variables will get a `0` value by default.

On the other hand, if the `Time2(int hour,int minute,int seconds)` constructor contained some additional logic (such as computing the value of some other instance variable), these two implementations of the parameter-less constructor would have different behavior.

Comment: different behaviour can be run as default constructor?

Comment: @AHF I don't understand your comment. Calling one constructor from another constructor is usually done in order to reduce code duplication. Therefore, it may make sense to have the `this(0,0,0)` call in the parameter-less constructor, if the 3 arguments constructor contains some logic that all constructors should perform.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to provide an overloaded / parametrized constructor in order to use it in the default constructor:

```
public class TimeTwo {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int seconds;

    public TimeTwo() {
        /*
         * the overloaded constructor is used here,
         * you have to write this(...) because
         * you want to initialize the current object
         */
        this(0, 0, 0);
    }

    public TimeTwo(int hour, int minute, int second) {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.seconds = second;
    }
}
```

Another way to set default values could be done like this:

```
public class TimeTwo {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int seconds;

    public TimeTwo() {
        this.hour = 0;
        this.minute = 0;
        this.seconds = 0;
    }
}
```

There is even a third possibility of setting default values:

```
public class TimeTwo {
    private int hour = 0;
    private int minute = 0;
    private int seconds = 0;

    public TimeTwo() {}
}
```

Comment: Below 'Time2(int hour, int minute, int second)' is part of my code, but my major concern is why i need to write 'Time2(){this(0,0,0)}' and why not to write it as 'Time2(){}' what is difference

Comment: I think there is no need for writing `Time2() { this(0, 0, 0) }`, why do you think you have to? You can use one of the ways shown in my answer as well. See the edit in the first class example (added a comment).